# Parse hour and AM/PM value from a string - C#

Tags: c#, string, string-parsing

What would be the most effective way to parse the hour and AM/PM value from a string format like "9:00 PM" in C#?

Pseudocode:

```
string input = "9:00 PM";

//use algorithm

//end result
int hour = 9;
string AMPM = "PM";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
string input = "9:00 PM";

DateTime result;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(input, out result))
{
    // Handle
}

int hour = result.Hour == 0 ? 12 
           : result.Hour <= 12 ? result.Hour 
           : result.Hour - 12;
string AMPM = result.Hour < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
```

Comment: So I should post the same answer as everyone else?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DateTime result;
string input = "9:00 PM";

//use algorithm
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "h:mm tt", 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    //end result
    int hour = result.Hour > 12 ? result.Hour % 12 : result.Hour;
    string AMPM = result.ToString("tt");
}
```

Comment: Works in every culture.

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = "9:00 PM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(input);

int hour = int.Parse(dt.ToString("hh"));
string AMPM = dt.ToString("tt");
```

See [**Custom Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for getting information from a DateTime value in all kinds of formats.

Comment: why not:  `int hour = dt.Hour;`?

Comment: @Rubens Farias `dt.Hour` returns 21, not 9.

Comment: @Rubens your code thinks the format is 9 AM, so dt.Hour is the 9th hour. The hour property always returns the nth hour of the day.

Comment: @Rex - I get the following error "Input string was not in correct format" on `int hour = int Parse.(dt.ToString("h"))`

Comment: @Michael what is `dt.ToString("h"))`?

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.Parse:

```
string input = "9:00 PM";
DateTime parsed = DateTime.Parse(input);
int hour = int.Parse(dt.ToString("h"));
string AMPM = parsed.ToString("tt");
```

**Edit**: Removed %12 on hour since that fails for 12 AM.

Comment: didn't want to change to (h-1)%12+1?

Comment: @Jimmy, that still fails for 12 AM, since the DateTime.Hour would return 0 and (0-1)%12+1 = 0 not 12.

Comment: ouch. Thats what I get for testing functions using Python. nevertheless +11 should be the same :P

Answer (score 0):

begin pseudocode:

```
 DateTime dt;
 if (!DateTime.TryParse("9:00 AM", out dt))
 {
     //error
 }
```

end pseudocode

Comment: More *actualcode* than *pseudocode* :) (just incomplete)