# Parse hour and AM/PM value and add to existing time

Tags: c#

Similar question like the already one [Parse hour and AM/PM value from a string - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233691/parse-hour-and-am-pm-value-from-a-string-c-sharp) but i need some thing like this.

```
string input = "9:00 PM";
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
// Resultant time like this
currentTime.Add(input)   // Just a sudo
```

If current datetime like 9/6/2013 3:18 AM then result would be like this 9/6/2013 9:00 PM
How to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parse the string to datetime..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this;

```
string input = "9:00 PM";

if (input.IndexOf("PM") > 0)
{
     DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Date;
     int hour = Int32.Parse(input[0].ToString()) + 12;
     TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, hour, 0, 0, 0);
     Console.WriteLine(dt.Add(ts));
}
```

Output will be;

```
06.09.2013 21:00:00
```

Here a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/wBZcNL).

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick...

```
string input = "9:00 PM";
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(input);
```

Outputs present date with the input time.

> 9/6/2013 9:00 PM